# Is it necessary to put dual clutch transmission to park gear on stop and go traffic?

Tags: honda, transmission, hybrid, fit

I was advised to put my car which has dual clutch transmission, to park gear on heavy traffic to reduce stress on clutches. Is this correct? As far as I know holding brake will do the job. Since my service advisor advised this, now I'm confused.

Update:

Car is 2014 Honda fit hybrid GP5 Japan domestic model. Don't know whether clutch disengages on brake.

Comment: As a hybrid does it not do 'stop start'?  The engineers that designed this vehicle will most likely have thought to disengage the clutch when the brake is pressed.  You may be able to tell if you find a flat surface and very gradually release the brake, you should feel the point where the ECU decides it is time to engage the clutch.